# Best Practice to copy .vim and .vimrc to fresh server/terminal?

Tags: vim

Quite often I get access to a new server somewhere and I really prefer my own custom configured vim to the standard one.

What are some best practices to get a new vim behave like the one on you machine?

Its not as easy as scp or sftp, usually I have to ssh into these server across multiple hops and sometimes public key authentification is disabled (so no direct ssh tunnel :( )

I already tried zipping it and uploading it somewhere, but thats usually not very straight forward.

Any help is appeciated!

Comment: have you thought of git/mercurial...?

Comment: I have my 'dot' files `.bashrc`, `.vimrc`, etc. and my `.vim` folder in a git repository. Then I can just clone it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial for getting started with a dotfiles repository: https://medium.com/@webprolific/getting-started-with-dotfiles-43c3602fd789#.o97wkok0m

Keep in mind:

> To “activate” the dotfiles, you can either copy or symlink them from
>   the home directory. Otherwise they’re just sitting there being
>   useless.